# PHP filter_input: how to return NULL when it is empty from the input

Tags: php, filter, null, filter-input

How can I return NULL with `filter_input` when the input is empty?

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title');
var_dump($title);
```

it returns,

```
string '' (length=0)
```

but I want,

```
null
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **NULL** should have been `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`. But that doesn't do what you want either. Why do you need it to be NULL?

The reason you are getting string (0) is because the post field is available in the form. The field is just empty. If you want it to be **NULL** the field should not be there.

```php
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, array('options' => array('default' => NULL)));
var_dump($foo);
```

So go with `strlen()`. Or make sure the field is not there when you don't need it.